# MYSQL - how to return unique count on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to solve this query where I have two players with game scores. The query should return a chart of the players with the numbers of games and if the score was 3:0 or 0:3 then the player that score 3 gets 3 point otherwise any winning is for 2 points

My table:

```
    player1        player2   player1score  player2score
    -------        -------   -------------  ------------
    john            lee           3             0 
    maria           andy          1             3
    andy            john          1             3
```

the desired table should be like this:

```
    players        gamesplayed   points  
    -------        -----------   ------
    john            2               5 
    andy            2               2
    maria           1               0
    lee             1               0
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT players, count(*) gamesplayed
FROM (
    SELECT player1 AS players
    FROM table
    UNION
    SELECT player2 AS players
    FROM table
) players
```

But the query above returns the count of all players together and not individually in `gamesplayed`.

Can anyone see the problem? I'm also not sure hot implement the `points` column.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I think the fitting MySQL-Statement, just change it to a inline-view, have no mysql environment, plz excuse if the syntax isn't fully right:

```
SELECT player, 
    COUNT(player) AS gamesPlayed, SUM(score) score
FROM 
    (SELECT player1 AS player, 
        CASE 
            WHEN player1score - player2score > 2 THEN  + 3
            WHEN player1score - player2score > 0 THEN +2
            ELSE + 0
            END as score 
        FROM playerTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT player2 AS player, 
        CASE 
        WHEN player2score - player1score > 2 THEN  + 3
        WHEN player2score - player1score > 0 THEN +2
        ELSE + 0
        END AS score
    FROM playerTable) 
    AS playerSel
Group by player;
```

Comment: Briliiant! Thank so much :)

Comment: You can use SQL Fiddle to test queries where you don't have the environment handy - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I don't think you need the `+` signs in your `CASE` statements, and `COUNT(*)` is a better option than `COUNT(player)` IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for hints fiddle was down when I tried to use it

Comment: I don't know, but I have just started to always use one column in a count, I thought it probably is faster. Yes the + is not necessary thx

Answer (score 1):

Part of the difficulty is that you're using `UNION` which will get distinct values - so if a player played a game as player 1, and another game as player 2, he would only be counted once. In addition, if he played two games as player 1, he would only be counted once!

I think you want something like the following:

```
SELECT p1.player, COUNT(*) AS games_played, SUM(p1.player_score) AS total_points
  FROM (
    SELECT player1 AS player, player1score AS player_score
      FROM mytable
     UNION ALL
    SELECT player2 AS player, player2score AS player_score
      FROM mytable
) p1
 GROUP BY p1.player;
```

`UNION ALL` will preserve all the rows rather than just getting the distinct ones as `UNION` does.

Comment: thanks for you reply, however your solution is giving me an error "every derived table must have its own alias" then I fix this by adding `as player order BY player` in the end of the query, but that returns only one row with counting everything together :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot that you need an alias in MySQL for subqueries. Stand by, editing.

Answer (score 1):

Done in SQL-Server, dunno if it works with MySql:

```
WITH playerSel AS(
    SELECT player1 AS player, 
        CASE 
            WHEN player1score - player2score > 2 THEN  + 3
            WHEN player1score - player2score > 0 THEN +2
            ELSE + 0
            END as score 
        FROM playerTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT player2 AS player, 
        CASE 
        WHEN player2score - player1score > 2 THEN  + 3
        WHEN player2score - player1score > 0 THEN +2
        ELSE + 0
        END as score
    FROM playerTable)
SELECT player, 
    COUNT(player) AS gamesPlayed, SUM(score) score
FROM playerSel
Group by player;
```

I Retrieved the following Information:

andy;2;2
john;2;5
lee;1;0
maria;1;0

Comment: it may occur strange why I used with, but I didn't know how to group properly otherwise, because I would need to do that, based on the AGG-Functions used.

Comment: your query seems to be very correct, however MYSQL does not support `WITH` clause...so I'm stuck again :(